# dropdownlist value not show in code behind

Tags: javascript, c#

I have some items list in asp:dropdownlist, but when i want to read the value using :

```
string avalue=ddl.SelectedItem.Value;
```

it show an error said: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
The ddl Item=null.
But I check it using Javascript alert, it show value correctly.
Please help.

**UPDATE**

IN HTML

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlJTM" runat="server" Width="150px" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

IN Javascript

```
function test() {
    alert(document.getElementById("<%=ddlJTM.ClientID%>").value);
        }
```

IN C#

```
string value = ddlJTM.SelectedItem.Value;
```

Comment: can you post the method where you are checking the value ? also what is the name of the dropdown in markup aspx

Comment: Whenever you try to update the value of server  control using javascript. in that case value can be accessible to client side only not to code behind

Comment: post you Page_Load and data binding also

Comment: in ur asp code, ID = "ddlJTM", however in code behind you are refering to ddlJiaTM ?? it is wrong id, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're databinding in Page_Load, you're essentially also resetting the SelectedItem.

You should wrap whatever binding code that exists in Page_Load inside an if(!IsPostBack) block.

```
 if(!Page.IsPostBack)
 {

// Your binding code here ...

 }
```

Comment: I bind data from a button click code behind with some condition selected so I cannot bind it in page_load

Comment: every time your selected value change will call the post back method so SelectedItem will get empty ,you have to write bind insdie  if(!Page.IsPostBack)
 { }

Comment: I try as suggested, but still the same

Comment: after try all suggestion, I only can solve it by using EnableEventValidation="false"